# unable to find valid certification path to requested target - signed cert

Tags: ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am working on a code that connects to slack through a proxy which act as a MITM and replaces slack cert with its own self signed cert. I added proxy's cert into a trust store and configured my RestTemplate to use the trust store:

```
    def sslContext = new SslContextBuilder().withTrustStore(trustStoreResource, trustStorePassword).build()
    def proxy = proxyEnabled ? new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort) : null
    def httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setProxy(proxy).setSSLContext(sslContext).build()
    def result = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
```

That works fine. However, on my local I don't go through the proxy and connect to slack directly. In other words, the httpClient in the above code would be configured with SSLContext but not proxy. I was expecting this to be fine since Slack's cert is signed with a valid root CA but my code fails to verify Slack's cert.

I am assuming this is because my trustore but I am confused as why this is happening. Is it happening because root CAs are not imported in my trustsore? If so, how would I do that without having to maintain the root CAs?

I understand that locally I can refrain from setting up a trust store but I would like to avoid adding branches in the code if possible.

Comment: You don't seem to use the original SslContextBuilder from Apache commons http (I wasn't able to find the `withTrustStore` in it). The original SslContextBuilder from Apache commons http allows to add multiple trust stores (just call the method multiple times), hence you could load the system trust store + plus your custom one: https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/4.4.x/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.java#L218

Comment: I wrote that SslContextBuilder without checking if Apache had one. Thanks for your answer. Please post at as an answer and I will accept it. I need to find out how to load system trust store but I can probably figure that out

Comment: Hmm, after reading the documentation it doesn't look like loading multiple trust stores is going to work since SSLContext will pick only the first one in the list :(

Answer (score 0):

What I finally ended up doing was to use the implementation in https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/9b7fecb3647ecf1e3076 to combine system's default trust store with mine and then used the following class to build my SSL context. It's a shame HttpClient doesn't offer this but there might be a good reason for it.

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import java.security.KeyStore

class SslContextBuilder {

    private KeyManager[] keyManagers = []
    private TrustManager[] trustManagers = []

    SslContextBuilder withKeyStore(Resource resource, String password) {
        def keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance('JKS')
        keyStore.load(resource.getInputStream(), password.chars)
        KeyManagerFactory kmfactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        kmfactory.init(keyStore, password.chars)
        KeyManager[] kms = kmfactory.getKeyManagers()
        keyManagers += kms ? kms : []

        this
    }

    SslContextBuilder withTrustStore(Resource resource, String password) {
        def trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance('JKS')
        trustStore.load(resource.getInputStream(), password.chars)
        def tss = CompositeX509TrustManager.getTrustManagers(trustStore)
        trustManagers += tss ? tss : []

        this
    }

    SSLContext build() {
        def sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null)
        sslContext
    }
}
```